# PHP MySQL service get data from multiple id's

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a solution where I am using a PHP web-service to get data from a MYSQL database. At the moment its fine as I am passing single pieces of data for the query.

Now I am looking to use multiple id's in a search query so for instance I want to pull back a list of products based on multiple id's. I have put my current PHP service below and I have tried to modify this effectively to do what I need but just cant get there.

```
<?php

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/dbConnect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// check for post data
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];

// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // venues node
    $response["products"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $product= array();
        $product["id"] = $row["id"];
        $product["name"] = $row["name"];
        $product["type"] = $row["type"];

        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["products"], $product);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}

}
?>
```

This code works where I pass a single ID into the PHP and it gives me a single product back, However I want to be able to pass multiple id's to the PHP in an array maybe and then have these id's used in the query. I have tried the solution below but couldn't seem to get it to work, also I understand this PHP isn't the best especially for protecting against SQL Injection so any other suggestions around this are welcome.

```
WHERE id IN (' . implode(',', $ids) . ')';
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show me array values of $ids

Comment: First I think you're missing a `'` before the `WHERE id IN...`. Second, why didn't the solution work? Did you check out the query that was being produced? Because using `implode` or `join` like this, should work...

Comment: the array would be [2, 50, 236...] and the fully query row was $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN (' . implode(',', $ids) . ')" or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this 
this is for protecting injection

```
$ids = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string',$ids);
```

after that

```
 $sr=implode(",",$ids);

if($sr=='')
{
    $sr="''";
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN (".$sr.")" or die(mysql_error());
```